# Fill Bitmap with points

Tags: .net, wpf

I have an array of points and I want to create Bitmap with these points and some specified color (one color for all points). How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) or build the array of bytes separately and use regular BitmapSource with its method [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.create.aspx).

All you have to do is to prefill the bitmap with some background color and then set pixels in those points to the color you want.